# Good features of paths for machine learning

Tags: geometry, machine-learning, coordinates, geospatial

I'm looking into ML problems (mostly density estimation and anomaly detection) with paths made up of coordinates (GPS). Other than the coordinates themselves and deltas (changes between adjacent coordinate points) and polar coordinates what are some other good features? What features make intuitive attributes like straightness, curvy-ness, smoothness, and loopy-ness explicit?

Comment: This may be better for the statistics SE site, though there are some computer vision people here on SO.  You should probably clarify your question - asking for "good features" is likely to lead to closing of this question.  Or you might want to flag this for migration to statistics.SE.

Comment: Whilst no doubt stats folks can offer some insight; I think that SO has a more varied crowd that can answer this question from different areas. (I'm not really asking a stats question like how to model these features.) I think the question is well posed -- what features give explicit values to the intuitive attributes that we perceive in paths (I'm not sure how else to phrase that). Either way, it's a difficult question (one that I'm working on) just wanted to see if anyone has any insights

Comment: No offense, but you're probably barking up the wrong tree regarding ML.  Statistics and computer vision are the two areas that are most related to your topics: density estimation, anomaly detection, curve detection, path detection, and more.  There are some statistics folks on SO who work on analyzing animal movements, for instance, and that is why I think it could be useful here, along with the computer vision folks.  However, you're missing out on the statistical talent over on stats.SE if you don't post there.  It's better to focus on expertise than on hunting for an ML solution.

Comment: (Continued) Basically, focus on the problem domain and the tools used for such problems, rather than try to find ML hammers for the wrong problem.  For spatial and path modeling, there are far better tools and approaches available than one would find by starting anew with a general machine learning toolkit.  ML is alluring, but as you get more into it, you'll discover that the hard problems are best solved with very specific tools.

Comment: ML = Statistics + CS. So if you're ignoring any statistical results, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: You can also try http://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For straightness/curviness you may want to calculate an approximate first derivative of the curve, for smoothness the second and higher derivatives. 
If by loopiness you mean the tendency to return to places several times, you could for instance count how many segments intersect each other.

Comment: @Junier Out of curiosity, did you end up doing ML on such data?